# Issue updating image using OLEDB

Tags: c#, image, oledb

I work on C# window Visual Studio 2005. I save image on SQL Server using OLEDB command. In insertion I insert null value on image field. It works well, but a problem occurs when I try to update image. My update query is:

```
using (OleDbCommand Update = new OleDbCommand(
                 "UPDATE [BoardDetail] SET BoardImage= '(?)' WHERE BoardID='" + oItem.BoardID + "' AND BoardSerialNo='" + oItem.BoardSerialNo + "' ", connection))             
             {
                 OleDbParameter imageParameter =
                 Update.Parameters.Add("@image", OleDbType.Binary);
                 imageParameter.Value = content;
                 imageParameter.Size = content.Length;
                 Update.ExecuteNonQuery();
             }
```

it works well but value on image column is null.

Comment: can you assure that content is not null???

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with the definition of the parameter. Change:

```
SET BoardImage= '(?)'
```

to

```
SET BoardImage= @image
```